# Decorator Design Pattern with HashMap returning empty HashMap

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap, decorator

I am trying to implement Decorator design pattern for HashMap.

I have two Decorators - "UpperCaseHashMap" and "AddHashMap".

**Implementation 1 :-**

However, the result map contains only the effect of one of the decorators, example :-

- Only AddHashMap effect i.e. result is - {AA=AA}

  Map<String, String> map = new AddHashMap<>(new UpperCaseHashMap<>(new HashMap<> ()));
  map.add("aa", "aa");
  System.out.println(map);
- Only UpperCaseHashMap effect i.e. result is - {aaADDED_BY_DECORATOR=aa}

  Map<String, String> map = new UpperCaseHashMap<>(new AddHashMap<>(new HashMap<> ()));
  map.add("aa", "aa");
  System.out.println(map);

Below is the code of the decorator classes:-

```
    public class UpperCaseHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    Map<K, V> map;
    
    public UpperCaseHashMap() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    UpperCaseHashMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        String temp = key.toString().toUpperCase();
        key = (K) temp;
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
    
}

    public class AddHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    Map<K, V> map;
    AddHashMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        String temp = key.toString().concat("ADDED_BY_DECORATOR");
        key = (K) temp;
        return super.put(key, value);
        
    }
    
}
```

**Implementation 2 :-** - **The resulted map is empty**

public class AddHashMapImpl2<K, V> extends HashMapDecorator<K, V> {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Map<K, V> map;
AddHashMapImpl2(Map<K, V> map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    String temp = key.toString().concat("ADDED_BY_DECORATOR");
    key = (K) temp;
    return map.put(key, value);
    
}
```

}

```
public class UpperCaseHashMapImpl2<K, V> extends HashMapDecorator<K, V> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Map<K, V> map;

public UpperCaseHashMapImpl2() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
}

UpperCaseHashMapImpl2(Map<K, V> map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    String temp = key.toString().toUpperCase();
    key = (K) temp;
    return map.put(key, value);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
return super.put(key, value);
```

Is calling `HashMap.put` irrespective of the implementation of the map passed to the constructor. Instead you need:

```
return map.put(key, value);
```

However I feel you are probably misunderstanding how decorators work. If you are using subclassing you will need to forward every method to the delegate. At the moment your classes are extending `HashMap` but then delegating `put` specifically. This isn't going to work. All the other methods are going to go to the extended `HashMap` and won't find the data you've put into the delegate. You need to rethink your design.

You might want to consider a design like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MapDecorator<V> {
    V decorate(V value);
}

class DecoratedMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private final List<MapDecorator<V>> decorators = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addDecorator(MapDecorator<V> decorator) {
        decorators.add(decorator);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        for (MapDecorator<V> decorator: decorators)
            value = decorator.decorate(value);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I've used 'decorator' in this code to match your original question but, in reality, this is not using the decorator design pattern so, in reality, I'd use a different name such as 'transformer'.

Comment: Decorator Design Pattern depends upon sub-classing - https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/the-decorator-pattern-in-depth

Provided example seems to be using Visitor Design Pattern

Comment: Yes the map is empty for the reason I gave in the answer: you are only forwarding `put`. You would need to forward every method. Which would defeat the purpose of subclassing HashMap.

Comment: Can you please suggest some approach.
Also, can you please edit your answer (anything) so that I can upvote your answer